# dtype of ndarray containing string in python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I know that in case of ndarray containing strings, dtype returned will be of the form dtype(S#) where # denotes the length of the string.

[image: result of dtype attribute]

As shown in figure the array 'a' which is generated from a list [1,'2','3']. Once the array is created all the elements become string type. Array 'b' is created from a list ['1',2,'3'].

a.dtype gives S21 while b.dtype gives S1. Length of elements in both a and b is 1. Why the length of elements in first array is taken as 21 even though all the elements have length 1?

It is found that dtype will continue to be 'S21' even if 1 is replaced with  9223372036854775807. Once we use 9223372036854775808, dtype becomes 'S20'. How does this happen
Somebody please explain

Answer (score 0):

`np.array` is compiled code, so we'd have to dig into that to see exactly what is going on.  I don't recall seeing any documentation.  So the easiest thing is to just try some values and look for a pattern.

If the 1st element is a string it appears to use the longest string (or `str(i)` for numbers).

If the 1st is a number it appears to start with some default size.

Unless the `dtype` is truncating some of the strings, I wouldn't worry too much about this behavior.  If it matters, I'd suggest defining your own length.

Comment: I tried to make an array from list [True,'a']. generated array has dtype 'S5'. dtype shows 'S21' only when the 1st element in the list is an integer. If the first element is a float value, dtype of generated array is shown as 'S32'.

Comment: The other boolean is False with 5 characters.  The other values may be the maximum print width of integers and floats, or somehow connected to that..

Comment: You could also look at genfromtxt and how it chooses dtype when `dtype=None`.  If the column has mixed numbers and strings, or accidentally includes string headers. Most of that code is python.